# Mongodb Aggregation in Node.js to Spring Boot

Tags: node.js, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregate

I need to query the list of customers that the day and month of the date of birth (dob) is the same as plus 7 days of current date.

below is the query in node.js. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert the aggregation to Spring Boot.

```
//node.js
let date = moment();
    date = date.add(7, "day");
    db.customers.aggregate([
        { $match: { companyId: "COMPANY_ID" } },
        {
            $project: {
                customerName: 1,
                phone: 1,
                _id: 1,
                dob: 1,
                month: { $month: { $add: [new Date(), "$dob"] } },
                date: { $dayOfMonth: { $add: [new Date(), "$dob"] } },
                customerGroupId: 1,
                customerGroup: 1,
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                month: date.get("month"), date: date.get("date")
            }
        } 


//partially in spring boot.

public List<Customers> findCustomersByDOB (String companyId) {
        List<AggregationOperation> list = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();
        list.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("companyId").is(companyId)));
        list.add(Aggregation.project("companyId", "customerName", "customerGroup", "phone", "dob"));
        TypedAggregation<Customers> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Customers.class, list);
        
            return mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, Customers.class, Customers.class).getMappedResults();
    }
```

Comment: I havn't work with Dates. But did u try http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.

```
list.add(Aggregation.project("companyId", "customerName", "customerGroup", "phone", "dob")
.andExpression("month(toDate(dob))").as("month")
.andExpression("dayOfMonth(toDate(dob))").as("day"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! It works! :)

```
public List<Customers> findCustomersByDOB(String companyId) {
             LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
             LocalDate newDate = localDate.plusDays(7);
     List<AggregationOperation> list = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();
             list.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("companyId").is(companyId)));
             list.add(Aggregation.project("companyId", "customerName", "customerGroup", "phone", "dob")
                     .andExpression("month(toDate(dob))").as("month").andExpression("dayOfMonth(toDate(dob))").as("day"));
    list.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("month").is(newDate.getMonthValue()).and("day").is(newDate.getDayOfMonth())));
    TypedAggregation<Customers> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Customers.class, list);
            
                return mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, Customers.class, Customers.class).getMappedResults();
    }
```